# How to schedule a cron to run the first Thursday of every month

Tags: linux, cron, debian

I need to schedule a cron job to run at 3:00 PM on the first Thursday of every month. How can I do this?
I have read another topic similar to this, but it is for the first Sunday of every month. How do I modify this to suit my needs?

Every first Sunday of very month

```
00 09 * * 7 [ $(date +\%d) -le 07 ] && /run/your/script
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, given @pt1997's response below you should be able to figure out what which position in the line you posted above means; and with minimal thought you should, again w/ the into provided below, understand how to change it to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

from `man 1p crontab`

> INPUT FILES
>
> In  the POSIX locale, the user or application shall ensure that a crontab entry is a text file consisting
>          of lines of six fields each.  The fields shall be separated by "blank" characters. The first five  fields
>          shall be integer patterns that specify the following:
>
> ```
>     1. Minute [0,59]
>     2. Hour [0,23]
>     3. Day of the month [1,31]
>     4. Month of the year [1,12]
>     5. Day of the week ([0,6] with 0=Sunday)
> ```

I hope that helps.

Comment: No, it doesn't help me :(

Comment: @DannyBelanger: why not? Explain, we cannot read in your mind.

Comment: I know the minute, hour, day of the month, month of the year, and day of the week What I don't get is the rest.

I know what the first 7 is, it's Sunday but the 07 after -le What is that?

What my question was how do I modify this to become the Cron I need?
A simple answer would suffice, eg. This is how it should be

```
00 15 * * 4 [ $(date +\%d) -le 07 ] && /run/your/script
```
If that's even right.
Or is it this one
```
00 15 * * 4 [ $(date +\%d) -le 04 ] && /run/your/script
```
That's the type of answer I was looking for!
Thanks for the help. Really Appreciated.

Comment: Also in his answer he wrote that 0 is sunday but in the answer I found 7 is Sunday. So what is right and what is wrong?

Comment: I guess I'll have to ask the question again since it seems this one has become stale!

Comment: 0 and 7 is Sunday. 
`00 15 * *  4 [ $(date +\%d) -le 07 ] && /run/your/script`

Comment: and the `$(date +\%d) -le 07` just checks if `date +%d` is lower than 7 aka if we are in the first week of the month. 
See https://sysadminspot.com/linux/cron-to-run-on-first-specified-day-of-the-month/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The updated cron entry to run the first Thursday of every month is as follows:

```
00 15 * * 4 [ $(date +\%d) -le 07 ] && /run/your/script
```

this will run at 3pm every Thursday and run the specified command which can be broken down as follows:

`[ $(date +\%d) - le 07 ]` - returns the day of the month and checks if less than 7

`&& /run/your/script` - only if the previous condition is true (i.e. date is less than or equal to 7) will it run /run/your/script